# Typescript Omit property not working with 'as' keyword

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

During registration both property need but after it password won't need. 
The idea is, for registration and authencation the system will use firebase built in functions, but everything else system will store in firebase user collection.

My problem is, when i have two type of user (one for registration, one general type):

```
export interface RegistrationUser extends firebase.UserInfo {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export type User = Omit<RegistrationUser, 'password'>;

registerUser(user: RegistrationUser) {
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(()=> {
      let newUser = user as User;
      // save user prop to firebase user collection
      this.collection.add(newUser);
    });
}
```

Despite of 'as' keyword, the `password` property still saved.
How can I set to not save the password to user collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typescript don't really remove the property when you do something like this. It is just for static analysis type purposes (Typescript does not exists on runtime). To really remove the property you need to do something like this:

```js
const newUser: User = {email: user.email};
```

Comment: unfortunately i have bunch of prop (it was just demo for show my purpose)

Comment: I see... You will need to create another objects every time or use the "delete" operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: You can also use object destructuring like `const { password, ...newUser } = user;`, which will copy all (own enumerable) properties *except* `password` from `user` into `newUser`.